# Unhandled exception at 0x770115de in : 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccccc0 with recursive vector search

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2008, recursion

Unhandled exception at 0x770115de in daedalus_1.4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccccc0.

```
string temp;
string locName = "0";

vector<vector<string>> l;
int m = 100, n = 3; //vector dimension
l.resize(m);
for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i) l[i].resize(n);

temp.clear();

if(line.substr(1, 17) == "Timing LocationID" && arrayFull == true) {
    int i = 0; //starting char
    while (line[i++] != '='); //increment to next
    while (line[++i] != '"') temp += line[i];
    locName = findLocation(temp, 0, "", l);

string findLocation (string temp, int index, string locName, vector<vector<string>> &l)
{
    if (temp == "*") return locName; // <------errors here on return
    if (l[index][0] == temp) findLocation(l[index][1], 0, locName.insert(0,l[index][2]), l);
    else findLocation(temp, ++index, locName, l);
}
```

This function loops through a 2xvector and returns a concatenation string made of parent->child vector cells

these are from the call stack; looks like the string destructor

```
__CLR_OR_THIS_CALL ~basic_string()
    {   // destroy the string
    _Tidy(true);
    }

void __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL _Tidy(bool _Built = false,
    size_type _Newsize = 0)
    {   // initialize buffer, deallocating any storage
    if (!_Built)
        ;
    else if (_BUF_SIZE <= _Myres)
        {   // copy any leftovers to small buffer and deallocate
        _Elem *_Ptr = _Bx._Ptr;
        if (0 < _Newsize)
            _Traits_helper::copy_s<_Traits>(_Bx._Buf, _BUF_SIZE, _Ptr, _Newsize);
        _Mybase::_Alval.deallocate(_Ptr, _Myres + 1);
        }
    _Myres = _BUF_SIZE - 1;
    _Eos(_Newsize);
    }
```

Comment: Please show how you call the function.

Comment: Could it just be a bounds issue? Have you ruled that out? What is the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: locName = findLocation(temp, 0, "", l); Beginner so not sure what a bounds issue is - same for stack trace crash, but I will research these

Comment: Edit the question, show also how you populate `temp` and `l`. Preferably, build an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: not all control paths return a value in findLocation

Comment: @forest.peterson: it's really super important to show the actual code you're compiling here.

Comment: temp is also not assigned in the function and it can overflow the stack  or even access the vector out of bounds as index is not checked against the vector size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your function string findLocation ()

does not return value on all paths, maybe you meant:

```
string findLocation (string temp, int index, string locName, vector<vector<string>> &l)
{
    if (temp == "*") return locName;
    if (l[index][0] == temp) return findLocation(l[index][1], 0, locName.insert(0,l[index][2]), l);
    else return findLocation(temp, ++index, locName, l);
}
```

Comment: why are the 'return' necessary - should I go through the rest of my code and add these in similar situations?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly your code do, but your function must eventually return string. And yes, make all your functions return properly, if their return value is non-void. You should see warnings on that.